# Android Contacts display in list view

Tags: android

i am making a contacts backup app and want to display the contacts in a list view. The code that i have written is doing this, but the format of the info displayed is not right. I want to extract just the name and contact number from the info being displayed now in the list view. My code for doing this is as follows....Can anyone please just guide me how to extract the name and number from the contact info that is being generated here? i do not need the definite code, just point me to the direction i need to follow. Thanks

```
public class ContactsBackupMain extends Activity {

Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> vCard;
//String vfile;
File vfile;
Button btnCreateBackup;
static Context mContext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contacts_backup_main);
    mContext = ContactsBackupMain.this;
    // vfile = "Contacts" + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".vcf";

     btnCreateBackup = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCreateBackup);

     btnCreateBackup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             getContactsBackup();

             Intent intent = new Intent(ContactsBackupMain.this, DisplayListItems.class);
             intent.putExtra("vCard", vCard);
             startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contacts_backup_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private void getContactsBackup() {

    String path1 = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getPath() + "/external_sd/";

    File dir = new File(path1);
        if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();

         vfile = new File(dir, "Contacts.vcf");
         vfile.canWrite();


    vCard = new ArrayList<String>();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if(cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0)
    {
        cursor.moveToFirst();


        for(int i=0; i<cursor.getCount(); i++)
        {

            get(cursor);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Contact  " + (i+1) + "VCF String is " + vCard.get(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

    }else{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Contacts in Your Phone", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

Comment: try this link to get contacts : http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: @HarshitRathi thank you for your response. I actually already have the contacts and am being able to display them in a list view in another activity. The problem is the format in which the contacts are being displayed is this BEGIN:VCARD VERSION:2.1 N:VoiceDial;AT&T;;; FN:AT&T VoiceDial TEL;CEL;PREF:*08 END:VCARD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to extract the contacts and save it in a database and then display to your listview.. use the below code to extract the contacts

```
        try {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String hasPhone = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
            String name = cursor
                    .getString(cursor
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

            if ("1".equals(hasPhone) || Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) {
                // You know it has a number so now query it like this
                Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                    String dname = cursor
                            .getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    System.out.println("Name is " + dname);
                    String phoneNumber = phones
                            .getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    System.out.println("Phone Number is " + phoneNumber);
                    int itype = phones
                            .getInt(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

                    final boolean isMobile = itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE
                            || itype == ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE;

                    dbaccess.addContacts(name, phoneNumber);
                }
                phones.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I am actually making a vcf file in the sd card containing all the information of the contacts, so is it advisable to first store it in a database and then display that info as well as store that info only as backup in a vcf file? i am thinking in regard to memory management.